# Getting row information from click on a table cell

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

[image]

I'm trying to get the Flower Name and Location when a user clicks on the stars, so I can send the information to a database api endpoint.

I've tried getting the row information which works, but indexing into the row with `cell[0]` or `cell[1]` doesn't work.

```
let tr = star.parentElement.parentElement;
console.log(tr)
```

Console Output

```
  <tr class="odd">
    <td class="sorting_1">1</td>
    <td>flower</td>
    <td>Purple Roze Flower</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>3.5</td>
    <td>Ascend Montclair</td>
    ...
 </tr>
```

Comment: `e.target.closest('tr')` refers to the row, or `null` if there's no row in the ancestor path (unlike checking parents, this works also when there is any amount of elements inside the clicked cell). The row has `cells` collection, which you can use to target a cell with an index.

Comment: Can you include a more complete example of your HTML and JS, including the 'star' HTML and the JS logic used to attach the event handler.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is not working? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: First cell = `$(tr).find("td")[0]` (as tagged [tag:jquery] and you already have a `tr`) - however, as you're using [tag:datatables], you don't want "first" cell - from your example name would be `$(tr).find("td")[2]` - double-however, as you're using [tag:datatables], you should use the datables-api to get the source data for the row and use that.  Then it doesn't matter if the user re-orders the columns or you move them at a later date (don't rely on indexed positions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing out of, then back into the element seemed to do the trick.

```
let tr = star.parentElement.parentElement;
let id = tr.children[0].innerHTML;
let product_name = tr.children[2].innerHTML;
```